# Como insertar texto en dos textbox referenciando a un DataGridView en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

buenos días. Resulta que tengo dos textbox en mi aplicación hecha con Windows Forms, y necesito que los dos textbox se rellenen con texto del mismo dataGridView.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy al botón consulta se abre un DataGridView, con los datos de la tabla PERSONAL identificado por su nombre y Id. Cuando pulso con el ratón dos veces sobre una misma fila, el id de la persona la que he seleccionado se debe poner en el textBox **Desde Operario** y quiero que al darle al segundo botón de Consulta (el de Hasta Operario) se abre el mismo DataGridView y selecciona a otro operario y se pone en el TextBox de **Hasta Operario**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí viene el problema, cuando abre el segundo botón de consulta y me aparece el mismo DataGridView al seleccionar un nombre, en el textbox de **desde operario** se me pone el mismo que en el que yo selecciono para poner en el textbox **Hasta Operario**. 
Mando el código, por si me pueden ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

```
private void eCellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
            // Si el doble click se ha hecho en alguna celda de la cabecera no hacer nada
            if (e.RowIndex == -1)
            {
                return;
            }


            switch ((sender as Control).Name)
            {

                //DataGridView
                case "dgvPersonal":

                    Formulario_Consulta f1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Formulario_Consulta>().SingleOrDefault(); //Devuelve un solo elemento en la secuencia

                    if (f1 != null)//o sea el formulario de consulta está abierto y no se ha cerrado
                        {
                            int id_persona = (Int32)dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[ID_PERSONA].Value; //Sacamos el valor de la id persona correspondiente que al hacer doble click, sobre ella.
                            int id_persona2 = (Int32)dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[ID_PERSONA].Value; //Sacamos el valor de la id persona correspondiente que al hacer doble click, sobre ella.
                            f1.tb_Desde_Operario.Text = id_persona.ToString(); //y le añadimos al textbox correspondiente el id de la persona para hacer la pertinente consulta
                            f1.tb_Hasta_Operario.Text = id_persona2.ToString();
                            Close(); //Cierro el formulario de consulta del personal.
                        }

                    break;

                default:
                    //...
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema de estructura del programa, ya que el evento se ejecuta cada vez que das doble click a la grid, y por ende, te modifica los 2 textbox con el valor de la celda seleccionada.

Puedes solucionar tu problema con un sencillo `if` de la siguiente manera:

```
case "dgvPersonal":

    Formulario_Consulta f1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Formulario_Consulta>().SingleOrDefault(); //Devuelve un solo elemento en la secuencia

    if (f1 != null)//o sea el formulario de consulta está abierto y no se ha cerrado
    {
        if (f1.tb_Desde_Operario.Text == String.Empty) //Si tb_Desde_Operario no tiene texto, rellenamos tb_Desde_Operario
        {
            f1.tb_Desde_Operario.Text = (Int32)dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[ID_PERSONA].Value;
        }
        else if (f1.tb_Desde_Operario.Text != String.Empty && f1.tb_Hasta_Operario == String.Empty) //Si tb_Desde_Operario tiene texto y tb_Hasta_Operario no, rellenamos tb_Hasta_Operario
        {
            f1.tb_Hasta_Operario .Text = (Int32)dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[ID_PERSONA].Value;
        }
        else //Si las 2 tienen texto, rellenamos tb_Desde_Operario y vacíamos tb_Hasta_Operario
        {
            f1.tb_Desde_Operario.Text = (Int32)dgvPersonal.CurrentRow.Cells[ID_PERSONA].Value;
            f1.tb_Hasta_Operario.Text = String.Empty;
        }

        Close(); //Cierro el formulario de consulta del personal.
    }

    break;

default:
    //...
    break;
```

Comment: Gracias, por reponder tan rápido. No pude imaginar esa idea que me distes..

Comment: @SergioDavidPerezAcosta Nunca es tarde para aprender cosas nuevas :)

Comment: Lo que pasa es que si después quieres cambiar el valor del textbox 1 con el datagridview se me cambia el textbox de Hasta Operario y no el Desde Operario que es el que yo quisiese cambiar

Comment: @SergioDavidPerezAcosta Ya pensé que te pasaría eso, puedes hacerlo de muchas maneras diferentes, una de ellas es con otro `if` mirando si los 2 textbox tienen texto, que te cambie el de arriba y te vacíe el de abajo así a la proxima te rellenará el de abajo, te modifico la pregunta y te añado lo comentado

Comment: Ok, gracias por tu rápida respuesta

Comment: @SergioDavidPerezAcosta Ya lo tienes